# description environment missing in bioinfo class

Tags: lists, document-classes, description

Usually in my articles for the `\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}`, I use the `description` environment without getting any error, i.e. `\begin{description} … \end{description}`.
However, when I used the `\documentclass{bioinfo}` for the Oxford Bioinformatics journal template I got an error stating that the `description` environment is undefined.

Can anybody help me to figure out this issue?

Comment: The list environments (like `description`) are not defined in the LaTeX kernel but by the document classes. Seems `bioinfo` does not define it. IMHO it is thus broken, since `description` is a standard LaTeX environment - you should contact its authors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could grab the necessary details from [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls):

[image]

```
\documentclass{bioinfo}% http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/bioinformatics/for_authors/submission_online.html
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{description}% Taken from article.cls
               {\list{}{\labelwidth\z@ \itemindent-\leftmargin
                        \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}
               {\endlist}
\newcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
                                \normalfont\bfseries #1}
\setlength{\labelsep}{.5em}% Also taken from article.cls
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[An item] Here is a description on an item.
  \item[Another item] Here is a description on an item.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

You would have to include everything between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (inclusive).