# How to remove blank first page in document that contains only tables and figures

Tags: floats, blank-page

Actually I want to move my figures and tables to a separate LaTeX file.
But when I compiled that new file I got a blank first page.

So I want to know how can I remove that blank first page. By the way, I'm using the `bioinfo` class.

Comment: Post a MWE so we can see what you're working with.  We'll be better able to help you.

Comment: The question itself is different from [How to remove the blank page when omitting comments and messages in knitr](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86434/5764), although [the solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86633/5764) is similar. Not sure whether that would be considered a duplicate. [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) can be used to discard a page based on a condition.

Comment: I added \AtBeginShipout{\ifnum\value{page}=1\AtBeginShipoutDiscard\fi}
to my document but I got two errors of undefined Control sequence. Do I need to add a specific file in my work directory?

Comment: @Bel: You need to add the `atbegshi` package to your preamble: `\usepackage{atbegshi}`. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: @bel I'm afraid without MWE this question will be closed as too localized.

Comment: @Werner: Yes it does solve my problem.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I offer that it is the `bioinfo` class, which appears to have [other issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88371/description-environment-missing-in-bioinfo-class) as well, that is to blame.  A minimal LaTeX document using, for example, the `article` class with, for example, only figures in it ought not generate a blank first page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\fbox{\includegraphics{hare}}
\caption{The Common Hare}
\label{fig:lab}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Single Page Output]